# java internal interface in class throw Invalid parameter type error in xamarin android binding

Tags: android, xamarin, binding

after

1. I put the aar file in the binding project
2. add the v7appcompact nuget package
3. add the v7.recycle... nugget package
4. build the binding  project

The vs throw the warning build log and errors:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: CalendarViewDebugBinding, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>JARTOXML : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning : ignoring option UseSplitVerifier; support was removed in 8.0
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8801: Invalid parameter type com.henry.calendarview.SimpleMonthView.OnDayClickListener in method ViewHolder in managed type Com.Henry.Calendarview.SimpleMonthAdapter.ViewHolder.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8C00: For type Com.Henry.Calendarview.SimpleMonthAdapter, base interface com.henry.calendarview.SimpleMonthView.OnDayClickListener is invalid.
1>D:\TempApps\CalendarViewDebugBinding\CalendarViewDebugBinding\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Henry.Calendarview.SimpleMonthAdapter.cs(1105,86,1105,104): warning CS0114: 'SimpleMonthAdapter.OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup, int)' hides inherited member 'RecyclerView.Adapter.OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup, int)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.
1>D:\TempApps\CalendarViewDebugBinding\CalendarViewDebugBinding\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Henry.Calendarview.SimpleMonthAdapter.cs(9,23,9,41): error CS0534: 'SimpleMonthAdapter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'RecyclerView.Adapter.OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup, int)'
1>D:\TempApps\CalendarViewDebugBinding\CalendarViewDebugBinding\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Henry.Calendarview.SimpleMonthAdapter.cs(9,23,9,41): error CS0534: 'SimpleMonthAdapter' does not implement inherited abstract member 'RecyclerView.Adapter.OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder, int)'
1>D:\TempApps\CalendarViewDebugBinding\CalendarViewDebugBinding\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Henry.Calendarview.SimpleMonthAdapter.cs(17,95,17,124): error CS0535: 'SimpleMonthAdapter.CalendarDay' does not implement interface member 'IComparable.CompareTo(Object)'
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

So I go to the GitHub source project to find the type `OnDayClickListener` and found it is an interface in the `SimpleMonthView` class.

And,so , how to fix this build warning ?

here the aar(name is 'library-debug.aar ') file I put in GitHub :
[The_File](https://github.com/jingliancui/XamarinIOSBuildLog)

and here is the source project in GitHub :
[henry-newbie/CalendarView](https://github.com/henry-newbie/CalendarView)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I Use another library instead:
[dengshiwei/CalendarComponent](https://github.com/dengshiwei/CalendarComponent)